# I need a PHP query to grab data from the database and use in my bar charts for results

Tags: php, html, bootstrap-4, chart.js

I'm working on a small project and need some help with a PHP query. I essentially am writing a small eLearning type module, so as the user goes through the module, I will write in check points. However for now, I'm manually placing values inside my table in PHP myAdmin, what I need is the values that are saved into the checkPointMod (check point module) table, to be passed to my bar/pie charts on a users dashboard. I just need a really simple query, any help would be great!!

[image: Screenshot of my table:]

My attempt at trying something (which I may be completely off rails here...):

```
    $query = "SELECT * FROM `checkPointMod`";

echo $query;


//3.Execute -----------
$result = $conn -> query($query);



while($row = $result -> fetch_assoc())  // <- While there are still results, fetch those using the assoc array, which creates an array of results from the database using the fields as headings. The arrow is related to OO, it's similar to pass the query on the left to the parameter to the right
  {
    data: [<?php echo $row['mod1']; ?>, <?php echo $row['mod2']; ?>, <?php echo $row['mod3']; ?>, <?php echo $row['mod4']; ?>, <?php echo $row['mod5']; ?>],   //When you add the "" around a html tag, you don't need to open <html> & close.
  }



//4.Disconnect ---------
$conn -> close();
```

My pie chart code which works (with manually placing in the data values):

```
var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart");

var myDoughnutChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'doughnut',
    data: {
        labels: ["Time Management", "Career Coach", "Stress & Wellbeing", "Note Taking", "Exam Prep", "Presentations"],
        datasets: [{
            label: 'Module Tracker',
            data: [6, 4, 2, 0, 3, 1],
            backgroundColor: [
                'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
                'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
                'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
                'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
                'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)'
            ],
            borderColor: [
                'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
                'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
                'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
                'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'
            ],
            borderWidth: 1
        }]
    },
    options: {
        scales: {
            yAxes: [{
                ticks: {
                    beginAtZero:true
                }
            }]
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: What is the issue you are facing with the above code snippet ?

Comment: What have you tried to spot the error? The PHP code above looks like you should at least get a syntax error

Comment: Check the  documentation of the chart you are using. I think here the while code should be inside the php code. You can use an XHR call to fill the data array or a javascript file or php like you are using

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, what you have is correct, I tend to write my queries seperate from the chart to maintain seperation; eg:

```
<?php
$query="SELECT * FROM checkPointMod";
# echo $query;
$newArray = array();
$result = $conn->query($query);
while($row = $result -> fetch_assoc());  {
    $newArray[] = $row['mod1'];
    $newArray[] = $row['mod2'];
    $newArray[] = $row['mod3'];
    $newArray[] = $row['mod4'];
    $newArray[] = $row['mod5'];
}
$conn -> close();
?>
```

You can do a print_r to check the content of your array, if need be ...

Then in your chart section:

```
 data: [<?= $newArray ?>],
```

Hope that helps you get on you way ...

Comment: Hi @neophytte would you pop the php code in the html web page just above where I have placed the graph <canvas> tag?

Comment: With this particular code, I would place it as high up in the page as I could, where it makes sense to do so. But as another user pointed out above, when you get this working, you may want to change it to a jQuery/AJAX type of call under XHR, where you would have this code on a different page altogether. Let us know how you go.